# "Marry, in her buttocks: I found it out by the bogs."

Tags: william-shakespeare, wording-choice, the-comedy-of-errors

From *The Comedy of Errors*, [Act III Scene II](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/comedy_errors/comedy_errors.3.2.html):

> DROMIO OF SYRACUSE: No longer from head to foot than from hip to hip: she is spherical, like a globe; I could find out countries in her.
> ANTIPHOLUS OF SYRACUSE: In what part of her body stands Ireland?
> DROMIO OF SYRACUSE: Marry, in her buttocks: I found it out by the bogs.

This is funny to me as it plays on the double meaning of "bog" as a [habitat well known in Ireland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bog) and a [British slang word for toilet](https://www.insider.com/british-slang-that-will-confuse-anybody-who-didnt-grow-up-in-the-uk-2017-11). The latter meaning, however, feels to me like something relatively modern, and it doesn't *exactly* fit the context since one's buttocks wouldn't *contain* bogs/toilets, as barrenness might be found "in" her hands in the next exchange (although being laid open to pedantic nitpicking might be a price Shakespeare was willing to pay for such witty repartee). Did the slang meaning of "bog" as toilet exist in the late 16th century, or was Shakespeare playing on a different (perhaps etymologically related) slang meaning of "bogs"?

What would viewers in Shakespeare's day have made of this line in the play?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Stanley Wells's edition of the play (The New Penguin Shakespeare, 1972) has the following gloss for "bogs":

> bawdy; it is not certain whether *bog* meant "privy" in Shakespeare's time

R. A. Foakes's edition of *The Comedy of Errors* (The Arden Shakespeare, Routledge, 1962) does not gloss "bogs" at all.

*A Shakespeare Glossary* by C. T. Onions (revised by Robert D. Eagleson, Oxford University Press, 1986) has no entry for "bog".

Eugene F. Shewmaker's *Shakespeare's Language: A Glossary of Unfamiliar Words in His Plays and Poems* (Facts on File, 1996) has the following entry for "bogs":

> ref. to the bogs in Ireland; here in poss. wordplay with slang sense of "latrine": "Marry, sir, in her buttocks; I found it out by the bogs." *Errors*, III, ii, 115-116.

However, W. W. Skeat's *A Glossary of Tudor and Stuart Words, Especially from the Dramatists* (completed by A. L. Mayhew and published at the Clarendon Press in 1914) has the following entry for "bog":

> a privy, latrina, Shirley, *Witty Fair One*, iv. 6 (end).

And, indeed, James Shirley's play *The Witty Fair One* contains the following lines (quoted from [*The Best Plays*](https://www.google.de/books/edition/The_Best_Plays/zo9iDiLJTGUC?gbpv=1), 1888):

> [A cry within] A Teague! a Teague! Make way, for shame!
> *Mis. Bonavent*: I think they are started.
> *The two Runners cross the stage, followed by Lord Bonavent, Venture and others.*
> (...)
> [Exeunt all but Mis. Bonavent and Mis. Carol.]
> *Mis. Bonavent*: He may be in the bog anon.
> *Mis. Carol*: Can they tell what they do in this noise?
> Pray Heaven it do not break into the tombs
> At Westminster, and wake the dead.

*The Witty Fair One* dates from 1628, just over a decade after Shakespeare's death and it is not entirely obvious that "bogs" here means "latrine".

Following a hint from Gareth Rees, I found "boggard" in the Huloet's [*Abcedarium anglico latinum, pro tyrunculis Richardo Hulœto exscriptore*](https://archive.org/details/abcedariumanglic00hulo/page/n49/mode/2up), printed in 1552, but I found that entry too difficult to decipher (except for the last word "Siege").

However, [*Huloets dictionarie newelye corrected, amended, set in order and enlarged ...* by Richard Huloet](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/t/text/text-idx?c=eebo;idno=A03825.0001.001), printed in London in 1572 has the following entry for [siege](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A03825.0001.001/1:10.153?rgn=div2;view=fulltext), which lists "bogard" as a synonym, making it plausible that Shakespeare used "bogs" also in this sense:

> *Siege, iacques, bogard, or draught*. Latrina, ae, Fo∣rica, ae. f. g. *Vn priue*, ou *retraict. S*.

Comment: The *OED* has "boggard" with a very clear citation from 1552 (Huloet, *Abcedarium Anglico Latinum*, "Siege, jacques, bogard, or draught, latrina") so it is plausible that "bog" meaning "latrine" was known to Shakespeare.

Comment: In Huloet (1552) you want the [entry for "siege", here](https://archive.org/details/abcedariumanglic00hulo/page/n347/mode/2up). The entry for "bogard" says "Boggarde or drawght. Loke [look] in Siege"

Comment: Regarding the aspect that "one's buttocks wouldn't contain bogs/toilets", one could parse "I found it out by the bogs" to mean that Dromio had opportunity to see the lady's buttocks while she was at the latrine.